# Facebook API - Unable to get insights data using a business object

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've tried to execute the following scripts example from: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/sdks/python/business/v2.5

```
from facebookads.objects import Business, Campaign, Ad, AdAccount, AsyncJob, Insights
business = Business('827904997241579')
insights = business.get_insights(fields=[
    Insights.Field.campaign_id,
    Insights.Field.unique_clicks,
    Insights.Field.impressions,
], params={
    'level': Insights.Level.ad,
    'date_preset': Insights.Preset.yesterday,
})
print insights
```

However, it returns an empty list. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you receiving an exception? If not, are you sure that there's data for the fields, dates, objects you requested? If there's no data to return to you at all the response from the API is an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a reply from Facebook.

It seems the business.insights endpoint is not supported.

The example in the python SDK page is likely an error.